# Where can I see the most recent updated time and the other things list in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

Where can I see the most recent updated time and the other things list in windows 7 and is there any way to reverse it back once after updating the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel, then Programs and Features, then choose View Installed Updates. From there, you can request to have
a selected update uninstalled. You can also do all this from the Windows Update utility. Microsoft's help page is here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Remove-an-update.

Comment: In the case of updating an OS, note that some updates cannot be uninstalled. You should think about  making a backup for those updates.

Comment: @raj also . .  in the "event viewer" Windows Logs, Setup, you can see the actual package number that was installed, and time that it was installed. using the number, back on the MStech site , you can often get more information about what exactally was changed. Lately more of the updates are more uninstallable than before , due to the complex system of isolation, and nothing ever leaving anymore :-)